# Navigate up and down in "screen" (command) linux

Tags: ubuntu, display, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After running a script in "screen" command in linux terminal, I identified that Im not able to scroll up or down. The entire screen is frozen and I'm just able to see whatever new messages and warnings i get from the script (on the current window) and not able to go up or down to see the old messages/warning.

How to navigate up or down ?

Answer (score 2):

Screen has its own scroll buffer, as it is a terminal multiplexer and has
to deal with multiple buffers.

You can disable the alternate text buffer in the xterm termcap info
inside screen. When disabled you can use the scroll bars (and mouse wheel)
to scroll up and down.

Add this to `~/.screenrc`:

```
# Enable mouse scrolling and scroll bar history scrolling
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
```

For more information see the post
[Can mouse wheel scrolling work in a Screen session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18006/can-mouse-wheel-scrolling-work-in-a-screen-session)

---

Another method that is more native to screen is described in an
[answer by njsg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40243/17660):

> Maybe there's a better way, but I'm used to scrolling using the "copy
> mode" (which you can use to copy text using screen itself, although
> that requires the paste command too):
>
> - Hit your screen prefix combination (`C-a` / <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> by default), then hit
>   <kbd>Escape</kbd>.
> - Move up/down with the arrow keys (<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>).
> - When you're done, hit <kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>Escape</kbd> to get back to the end of the scroll buffer.
>
> (If instead of <kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>Escape</kbd> you hit
> <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> and then move the cursor, you
> will be selecting text to copy, and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or
> <kbd>Return</kbd> a second time will copy it. Then you can paste with
> `C-a` followed by `]`.)
>
> Of course, you can always use `more` and `less`, two commonly used
> pagers, which may be enough for some commands.